# When using css animation to alter background-color, how do I maintain the state change?

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to animate the alpha value of div.

I've figured out how to do this using animations.
So using animations I can alter the background color of a div using :hover.
I can do a reverse-ordered version of the same animation when taking the mouse out of the div by using the :not(:hover) selector.

The problem comes up on the hover. The animation is performed, changing from the initial color to the destination color. But as soon as that animation is complete, the background color changes back to the initial color even if the mouse remains in the div.

'https://codepen.io/bobdobbs_/pen/KKBNLVM

How do I make the div keep the colour that it was animated to?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with ["animation-fill-mode"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) .

```css
.container {
  width: 500px ;
  height: 500px ;
  border: 2px solid #000 ;
  background-color: #a6a3d5 ;
}
.container:hover {
  animation: colour-change ;
  animation-iteration-count: 1 ;
  animation-duration: 0.4s ;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; // I just add this line
}
.container:not(:hover) {
  animation: reverse-colour-change ;
  animation-iteration-count: 1 ;
  animation-duration: 0.4s ;
}
@keyframes colour-change {
    0% {
  background-color: #a6a3d5 ;
    }
    100% {
  background-color: #a6a3d5c4 ;
    }  
}
@keyframes reverse-colour-change {
    0% {
  background-color: #a6a3d5c4 ;
  }
    100% {
   background-color: #a6a3d5 ;
    }  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <p>inside the container</p>
  
</div>
```

**But**, I suggest you another way using ["transition"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

```css
.container {
  width: 500px ;
  height: 500px ;
  border: 2px solid #000 ;
  background-color: #a6a3d5 ;
  transition: background-color ease 0.4s
}
.container:hover {
  background-color: #a6a3d5c4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <p>inside the container</p>
  
</div>
```